# Programmatically created field doesn't appear in Views fields

Tags: views, entities

Here is my little module that adds "markup" field to commerce_product table, but I can't select and display it in Views:

```
function comm_markup_schema_alter(&$schema) {
  $schema['commerce_product']['fields']['markup'] = array(
    'type' => 'float',
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => 1,
    'description' => 'Price markup field',
  );
}

function comm_markup_install() {
  $schema = drupal_get_schema('commerce_product');
  db_add_field('commerce_product', 'markup', $schema['fields']['markup']);
}

function comm_markup_uninstall() {
  db_drop_field('commerce_product', 'markup');
}

function comm_markup_entity_property_info_alter(&$info) {
  $properties = &$info['commerce_product']['properties'];
  $properties['markup'] = array(
    'label' => t('Price markup'),
    'type' => 'decimal',
    'description' => 'Gross price multiplier (defines profit amount).',
    'schema field' => 'markup',
    'getter callback' => 'entity_property_verbatim_get',
    'setter callback' => 'entity_property_verbatim_set',
  );
}
```

UPD:

```
function comm_markup_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  $data['commerce_product']['markup'] = array(
    'title' => t('Price markup field'),
    'help' => t('Multiplier. Adds profit to the gross price.'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_numeric',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ),
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric',
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you manually describe the new field to views, it won't know about it. You can do that with [`hook_view_data_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data_alter/7):

```
function MYMODULE_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  $data['commerce_product']['markup'] = array(
    'title' => t('Price markup field'),
    'help' => t('An amazing field which does something great'),
    // Add the rest of the definition here...
  );
}
```